# Swift - UIView.text Showing Up as Nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, option-type

I am a Swift beginner. I am creating a simple Parse notepad iOS app, for practice. I am trying to access from one class a uitextview created in another class.  This leads to an error the uitextview is nil.

For example, my tableviewcell class is very simple and only has two uiviews connected to it (the outlets are connected properly):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UITextView!

 override func awakeFromNib() {
        titleLabel.text = "Title"
        descriptionLabel.text = "Description"
    }
```

I then try and access these properties from my detailviewcontroller class, but the error  **"unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional"** comes up, even though my titleLabel and descriptionLabel both have values that are set programmatically.

detailviewcontroller class (this is in viewdidload):

```
let customCell = TableViewCell()

    var Title = customCell.titleLabel.text
    let Description = customCell.descriptionLabel.text
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

*Also please note that my IBOutlets are connected properly

Comment: Any update on this? Im facing the same!

Answer (score -1):

problem in this line only

```
let customCell = TableViewCell()
```

there can be many ways to pass the value to DetailViewController, if you are changing your views via segue, you can use this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    //add if condition with segue identifier for proper functioning of this code

    let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let customCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath( selectedIndexPath ) as! TableViewCell

    let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
    destinationViewController.Title = customCell.titleLabel.text!
    destinationViewController.Description = customCell.descriptionLabel.text!
    //you can set other properties too here
}
```

in your DetailViewController declare variables Title and Description outside the function viewdidload

Comment: Don't dequeue a new cell in `willSelectRow...`, get the current cell by using `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)`

Comment: Why `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @pratikxman But I want to be able to access the cell in detailviewcontroller, not masterviewcontroller. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: @pratikxman thank you so much for your answer. I only have one more problem which is that for some reason the prepareForSegue function is not being called (I put it in detailviewcontroller). Do you know why this could be? Thanks.

Comment: @StephaneHatgiskessell above code function prepareForSegue should be in your tableviewcontroller and it will work only when transition is done by segue. can you explain how you are going from tableviewcontroller to detailviewcontroller and coming back to tableviewcontroller

Comment: @pratikxman I would prefer to keep everything parse related in my detailviewcontroller. Is this possible? Thanks.